# Changing default style in notification list to BigTextStyle

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I have a method which receives text from a push notification, via the Parse API, and packages it into a notification object. Pretty standard stuff. My problem is that I'm trying to use a BigTextStyle to display my notification in the list, but it refuses to do so, and only shows one line of text and the two-finger gesture does not cause it to expand.

However, if I tap the notification, which opens the app, then return to the notification list, it is displayed in the BigTextStyle and is responsive to gestures. So, my guess is that somehow tapping on the notification is activating it and allowing the BigTextStyle code to kick in.

I like that tapping on the notification opens the app, but I don't want to force my users to open the app then close it again to see the full text of my messages. So is there a way I could either make the notification display in the BigTextStyle format from the start, or to make it so that the first click "activates" the notification, allowing the full message text to be seen, and then a second click opens the app? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code from the Notification method:

```
    public void receiveNotification() {


    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bts = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bts.bigText(SplashActivity.globalDataString);
    bts.setSummaryText("Tap to open app, swipe to dismiss message");

    NotificationCompat.Builder m = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    m.setContentTitle("New Push Notification")
        .setContentText(SplashActivity.globalDataString)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setStyle(bts)
        .build();

    Intent openApp = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);

    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // the application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MenuActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openApp);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    m.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify(pushMessageID, m.build());
    pushMessageID++;

    //reset notification
    flag1 = false;


}
```

**EDIT:** I think my problem is with where I'm calling my receiveNotification() method from. Right now I have it in the onCreate() method of my app's starting activity, which doesn't make much sense looking back. Should I put it in my broadcastReceiver class, or would there be a better place to put it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `build()` twice?

Comment: Because of an oversight when copying sample code from the Android dev site. I had actually noticed that before and I've tried recoding so there's only one. It doesn't seem to make any notable difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the creation and display of the notification is usually done either in the broadcast receiver, or in an intent service started by the broadcast receiver. Only when the user taps the notification, the relevant activity is launched. You can see Google's client code sample [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So, if I just wanted to move the code and call to my BroadcastReceiver, what would be the best way to reference the app's context to replace all the no-longer-functional calls to 'this'?

Comment: @SteveEckert Well, the `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver` has a `Context` parameter, so you can use that.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. I'll upvote this as soon as I've accumulated enough rep to do so :P

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand where is the answer to: "Changing default style in notification list to BigTextStyle"

Comment: I create a notification with bigtextstyle in a service, nevertheless the default is showing a normal notification only expanded on demand (when scrolling down the notification itself).